# How to get `python` to run Python 3 in WSL bash?

Tags: python, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I type `python` into my bash shell (Windows Subsystem for Linux) in Windows 10 Home, I get the following error message:

```
The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-minimal
 * python3
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

I've tried installing `python3` but am told it's already installed and up to date.

I've tried uninstalling `python-minimal` but am told it's not installed (!)

Why am I seeing two "competing" packages for Python? How can I fix the conflict and configure my WSL bash to run Python 3 from `python`?

Comment: You could do `python3`, otherwise, do `type -a python` and it will give you an idea of what you have change.

Comment: Thanks. I need it to run from `python`. `type -a python` gives me: `-bash: type: python: not found`

Comment: create an [alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html): `alias python="python3"`.  If you're managing many versions of python, you might want to look into [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: `python` in linux world as a CLI command almost always means `python2` and not `python3`. Make sure that you have `python2` installed (`sudo apt install python`). DO NOT alias python to python3 - this is some bad advice! To run python3, you have to specify `python3` on the CLI.

Comment: @srdjan-grubor thank you. Installing `python` (v2.7) did the trick and I now understand that for v3.6 I need to stick with `python3`

Comment: @SrdjanGrubor I don't see why an alias would be bad (assuming you don't want to manually run python2 at some point).  It's not a symlink.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Aliases are fine when they don't map to a legitimate command but if he had this `python`->`python3` alias and then ran some script that had `python <do_someting>` in it, the shell would try to invoke `python3` when the writer of that script was explicitly intending to run `<do_something>` on `python2` so it would likely break. That plus the fact that most Linux bin commands are actually python scripts, this would cause all kinds of funky problems.

Comment: A system script should use a shebang such as "#!/usr/bin/python" or "#!/usr/bin/python3". Even "#!/usr/bin/env python" wouldn't be an issue with aliases. Also, aliases aren't available in shell scripts, at least not normally. I see no practical problem with assigning a "python" alias for the interactive shell, though the OP should really get in the habit of developing with virtual environments, in which case this isn't an issue.

Comment: @srdjan-grubor would you like to post your solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @urig Copy pasted it :)

Comment: [Python 2 is dead](https://pythonclock.org/). `python` should run Python 3.x. If you have a script that relies on Python 2, use the full path to your binary. `$PATH` is to help humans, not scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`python` in linux world as a CLI command almost always means `python2` and not `python3`. Make sure that you have `python2` installed (`sudo apt install python`).

*DO NOT* alias `python` to `python3` - this is some bad advice!

To run `python3`, you have to specify `python3` on the CLI.

Comment: Not an answer and not a good advice or bad, it is just a preference of developer, this should not be an answer at all.

Comment: No. [`python2` is dead](https://pythonclock.org). `python` should run Python 3.x.

Answer (score 15):

If you're running Ubuntu 20 under WSL, there is a new package called `python-is-python3`:

```
cameron@Nook:/mnt/c/Users/camer$ sudo apt install python-is-python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-is-python3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2364 B of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python-is-python3 all 3.8.2-4 [2364 B]
Fetched 2364 B in 0s (7208 B/s)
Selecting previously unselected package python-is-python3.
(Reading database ... 33571 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-is-python3_3.8.2-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-is-python3 (3.8.2-4) ...
Setting up python-is-python3 (3.8.2-4) ...
cameron@Nook:/mnt/c/Users/camer$ python --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Alternatively, you could use `update-alternatives`:

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python $(readlink -f $(which python3)) 3
```