# Why does Python's unittest give "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported." in WSL bash?

Tags: python, windows, bash, python-unittest

On Windows, I have a Python code base with some unit tests (based on `unittest`) in sub-folders.

I use the Windows Command Prompt to change to the folder and run all tests using `python -m unittest subfolder/tests.py`. The tests in the file are then detected and run.

When I try to do the same in the Windows Subsystem for Linux bash shell, I get the following error with stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

**Why does this error occur in WSL bash but not in cmd? How can I fix this to work in both?**

PS - Here is an example of a `tests.py` as referred to above:

```
import unittest
from target import target

class tests(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_pi(self):
      expected = 3.1415926
      actual = truncate(target.pi(), 7)
      self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

  def truncate(num, digits):
      return int(num * 10**digits) / 10**digits

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What does this have to do with CMD. It is about BASH.

Comment: I mention cmd because it shows that my code is setup correctly for `unittest` to find and run the tests.

Answer (score 14):

Try to first change directory to `<test_cases_dir>` and then run the command **without** the .py suffix

from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface)

```
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass
```

in your example:

```
cd subfolder
python -m unittest tests.tests
```

---

(for the enthusiasts only)
from **unittest** implementation, a relative path cannot be imported:

```
def loadTestsFromName(self, name, module=None):
"""Return a suite of all tests cases given a string specifier.

The name may resolve either to a module, a test case class, a
test method within a test case class, or a callable object which
returns a TestCase or TestSuite instance.

The method optionally resolves the names relative to a given module.
"""
parts = name.split('.')
if module is None:
    parts_copy = parts[:]
    while parts_copy:
        try:
            module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
            break
        except ImportError:
 . . .
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work for me. When I cd into the sub-folder, then `python -m unittest test_module.TestClass` yields "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestClass'". `python -m unittest test_module` doesn't find any tests and yields "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s"

Comment: I think I've found the solution. Instead of invoking `python` in WSL bash, I should have been invoking `python3`. Having done that, tests are identified and run correctly. (More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524196/how-to-get-python-to-run-python-3-in-wsl-bash?noredirect=1#comment84059168_48524196)